# "gem install rails" is 100% and the "rails" is in the "gem list", but I failed to run "rails -v"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have install rails by gem. When it finished 100%. I checked it in the gem list. But I failed to run "rails -v". You can get more info as bellows

```
[root@wlin log]# gem list
... suppresed ....
[root@wlin log]# rails -v
bash: rails: not found the command...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get bash cannot find the `rails` command is probably because `rails` is not in the `PATH` variable.
To add it to the `PATH`, you can do

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/rails`

where `/path/to/rails` indicates the absolute path of the `rails` executable.
I am not sure what platform you are on, but you can find where this lives by looking for the `bin` folder in the rails subdirectory of the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` which can be found by calling

`gem env`

I hope this solves your problem! :)